# Проблема с .htaccess, подмена адреса

Tags: .htaccess

Нужно сделать из ссылки вида: http://m-camper.ru/item.php?urlname=burstner_lux

Ссылку: http://m-camper.ru/burstner_lux

В .htaccess пишу такой код (пока что пытаюсь сделать хотя бы http://m-camper.ru/burstner_lux.html):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /item.php?urlname=$1 [L]
```

Но ничего ссылкой не происходит. Если в .htaccess писать просто RewriteCond какое-то и потом перенаправлять страницу, то всё работает. Мб ли проблема в сервере? мб что-то отключено для такой операции?

Comment: Вопрос исчерпан я думаю?  
http://m-camper.ru/item.php?urlname=burstner_lux  
и  
http://m-camper.ru/burstner_lux.html
ведут на одну страницу.  
Как решили проблему?

Comment: P.S. Удалите с сервера info.php - это уже по сути уязвимость.  
Или переименуйте его в что-то не очевидное.

Comment: Честно, никак не решала) заработало)

теперь только почему-то .html не обрезается

Comment: Чтобы обрезалось выражение должно быть такое примерно:  

    ^(\w+)$
Если Вас не устроит- пишите, поможем :) Это выражение позволяет буквы от A до Z, цифры и **_** в адресной строке, любой другой символ заставит выражение не сработать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте, если не работает, значит проблемы с сервером

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ /item.php?u=$1 [L]
```

Comment: подобная проблема может возникнуть если на сервере(apache) имеются ещё какие-либо модули работающие с адресом запроса

Answer (score 0):

Можно немного воспользоваться идеей из паттерна проектирования MVC, в хтаккесс дообавить перенаправление всех запросов, а в index.php ловить и разбивать с помощью explode

**Вот .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

**Вот php**

```
$routes = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

и тут уже на вашу фантазию)